# Error "'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'" when using Weaviate.add_documents

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain, weaviate

I have the following piece of code:

```
if file.filename.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
                        pdf = ep.PDFLoad(file_path)  # this is the loader from langchain
                        doc = pdf.load()
                        archivo = crear_archivo(doc, file)
```

Inside `crear_archivo` function I am splitting the document and sending it to the `Weaviate.add_documents`:

```
   cliente = db.NewVect()  # This one creates the weaviate.client
    text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
    docs = text_splitter.split_documents(document)

    embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    return Weaviate.add_documents(docs, embeddings, client=client, weaviate_url=EnvVect.Host, by_text=False,      index_name="LangChain") 
# using this instead of from_documents since I don't want to initialize a new vectorstore         

# Some more logic to save the doc to another database
```

Whenever I try to run the code it breaks during the `Weaviate.add_documents()` function prompting the following error:
`'tuple' object has no attribute 'page_content'`.
I tried to check the type of `docs`, but that doesn't seem wrong since it returns a `List[Document]` which is the same type the function accepts.

How can I make it work? I kind of followed [this approach](https://github.com/langchain-ai/chat-langchain/blob/master/ingest.py) but the difference is I am loading files such as PDF, txt etc.

Comment: Is `Weaviate` a class which you meant to instantiate?

Comment: @mrkrieger1 No, because I am sending it the client which is an instance of  `weaviate-client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(También soy nuevo acá)

The error you're getting is likely because `docs` isn't a Document object.

AFAIK, a *"Document"* in LangChain is a list of `Document` objects. If you run `type(docs[0])` you should get `langchain.schema.document.Document`. This Document object is a dictionary with two keys: one is `page_content:` which accepts string values, and the second key is `metadata:` which only accepts dictionaries. `{page_content: str, metadata: dict}`. Not very well explained in LangChain's documentation.

My suggestions to tackle your problem:

1. Make sure that the `document` you're splitting here `docs = text_splitter.split_documents(document)`, is effectively a LangChain Document object. Use `print(document)`, and you should see this in the first line: `[Document(page_content='your text etc...` and at the end of the output, you should see `...end of your text', metadata={'...`
2. If `document` isn't a LangChain Document, you'll need to check how you created it.
3. If `document` is a LangChain Document, try `Weaviate.from_documents()` instead.

Hope this helps, y un abrazo!

Comment: Jajaja, Gracias genio!
Finally I could make it work. Yes, the problem was inside the List[Document] type, even though it was the expected return, the problem still lied there. Going back and forth with the usage of another function called `Weaviate.add_texts()` I could make it work after a lot of debugging, and now I am using add_documents. it's odd, but it worked using `RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter` instead of `CharacterTextSplitter` showcased in the LangChain documentation. Thanks for the help!